# file_get_contents does not return all the images in PHP

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I am trying to get all the images from a webpage based on a URL. Inspecting the webpage using Google Chrome, I can see the image but when using file_get_contents method, I am not getting the image.

```
public function getPictureFromUrl($url){
    $html = file_get_contents($url);
    $sContent = htmlspecialchars($html);
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($sContent);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($images as $image) {   
        $src = $image->getAttribute('src');
        return $src;
    }

    return "";      
}
```

$images length is 0.
The two following links are an example of what I tried as URL:

- [Samsung Website](http://www.samsung.com/us/televisions-home-theater/tvs/4k-uhd-tvs/65-class-ku6300-6-series-4k-uhd-tv-2016-model-un65ku6300fxza/)
- [Amazon Website](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01E6BHEFW)

I am not able to get the TV img src from this code.

How can I get the image source?

Comment: Because Amazon is not using `img` tag for those images

Comment: It might use Javascript to add the images to the DOM.

Comment: @HSaiKiran, as per what I saw, it uses img. Can you explain?

Comment: @Barmar, please emphasis.

Comment: I think the site is actually checking the user agent. I tried accessing it with `curl` and I got an error page, not the same page I get with a browser.

Comment: the images on amazon do not use img tag they use data:image and data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/91Td0PfLbXL._SL1500_.jpg

Comment: I have updated the post with an additional website example. I saw that it use img tag (using inspect option in Google Chrome)

Comment: @ehh but most of the images are loaded in the DOM later with Javascript, they are no initially available on the html content, and your `file_get_contents($url);` do not take javascript code into account.

Comment: Is there a way to get them from the js?